# Calculus in Banach Spaces Reference Request

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Can anyone suggest a text that gives a complete/thorough treatment of calculus in Banach spaces? Perhaps something something along the lines of Chapter 2 in [Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications](http://books.google.com/books/about/Manifolds_tensor_analysis_and_applicatio.html?id=dWHet_zgyCAC) by Marsen, et. al. but more expansive?

Thanks.

Comment: Look for texts named "nonlinear analysis" (or something similar) in their name. You're bound to find something you like.

Comment: Related to Mark Schwarzmann's comment: many books on PDE contain material similar to this. The words Bochner integral and Frechet derivative may be useful for searches.

Answer (score 7):

I studied it from Cartan's book: Differential Calculus. I found it a good exposition of the theory. That's my indication :)

Answer (score 5):

The only one I know is Jean Dieudonne's classic *Foundations of Modern Analysis*, which is the also the most cited out of print text I know. It's kind of strange since in the late 1960's and early 1970's, at the height of the Bourbaki Era, it was the single most cited analysis text for undergraduates and was fully expected to replace Rudin as the gold standard.

Anyway,I think you'll find exactly what you want in that text-if you're ready for it. It's a tough read-get your pencil and paper ready when you go to read it! there's now  an inexpensive edition.

Comment: This book is the first volume in Dieudonné's *Treatise on analysis*, which has many volumes.  I've never browsed the whole thing, and I don't know if the first volume has what would be called a "thorough treatment", but I agree it's worth checking out Chapter VIII.

Comment: For the part of classical analysis we generally call calculus on Banach spaces,yes,the first volume of Dieudonne's treatise is pretty complete,Jonas.The later volumes are considerably more advanced-and beyond volume 4,they get fairly specialized as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I suspect that only 3Sphere can verify whether it is complete/thorough to his or her liking.   I have some doubts due to there being only one chapter directly on the topic, which is much shorter than the chapter referred to in the question.

Comment: @Mathemagician Thank you for your suggestion; however, I'm hoping for something a little more pedagogical that would be easier to learn from and more focused on "Banach calculus", for lack of a better word.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is such a book in the common literature,3Sphere. The wonderful book ANALYSIS IN EUCLIDEAN SPACE by Kenneth Hoffman-now in Dover and reviewed by me for the Mathematical Association of America Online-has an entire chapter on how calculus behaves in Banach spaces. It's only a chapter,but it may be exactly what you're looking for.Also, Serge Lang's DIFFERENTIABLE MANIFOLDS and its' many alternate versions have brief and abstract treatments of differential calculus in Banach spaces.Lastly-Cartan's classic DIFFERENTIAL CALCULUS has a discussion of calculus in Banach spaces.

Comment: @Theo Apology accepted. In my younger days,believe me,my response wouldn't have been so civil. I've worked very hard under some IMPOSSIBLE conditions (a father dying of a protracted cancer illness,then my own illnesses). I don't take kindly to someone politely calling me an imbecile because I dared to make an error on a comment when I wasn't clear minded enough (2 hours sleep and up 20 hours) to properly think it through. But as I said,apology accepted and let's move on.

Answer (score 1):

Bourbaki's "Functions of one real variable" would do the job. It is quite expansive. You could even work in conjuction with with the Bourbaki volumes on Topology, and Topological vector spaces. But the pedagogical value is as always questionable.

Edit: If your aim is to learn analysis on Banach manifolds, then Serge Lang's book on differentiable manifolds is the answer.

Comment: These books may be too advanced for 3Sphere's purposes,George. That's the only problem-otherwise, there's a traincar full of good books on analysis in Banach spaces I could recommend.

Comment: @Andrew: The OP wanted a book detailing calculus on Banach spaces. If he had simply asked for an introductory book on Banach spaces, I would have mentioned some simpler book like G. F. Simmons or Rudin. But learning calculus on such generality as encompassing Banach Spaces -- that precisely is what Bourbaki is fond of.